# Calculate the closure and the interior of this set

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set $A=\{m+n\pi:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in $(\mathbb{R},d_u)$

Where $d_u$ is the usual distance. The exercise asks to calculate the closure, interior and boundary of that set.

Now, intuitively, it seems to me that the set is closed, and hence its closure is $A$, and also that its interior is empty, hence the boundary being $A$ as well.

The problem is that I don't know how to formalize this properly. i.e. I've tried considering a point $p\notin A$ and showing that there exists an open ball centered at $p$ that doesn't intersect $A$, but I can't find which radius to use.

I've also tried to show that its not possible to create a sequence of points from $A$ that converges to a point that is not in $A$, but again, I'm failing at the time of formalizing this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $ n\pi -[n\pi]$ is dense in $[0,1]$ where $[n \pi]$ denotes the floor function - that's a classic exercise. This shows that the closure of your set $A$  is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ because you can use the $m$ term to be $(k - [n\pi])$ for any integer $k$. $A$ is countable hence has empty interior which answers the other questions, so in fact the only trick is to observe the density thing

Edit: 
right, sorry, I assumed $n$ and $m$ were just integers, not necessary positive, my bad. anyway in case of natural numbers the question isn't so nice. you can easily see that for any interval $[0, T]$ with $T < \infty$ there are only finitely many elements of $A$ that can be in that interval (because you can just bound $m \leq T$ and $n \leq T/\pi$ which gives you finitely many possibilities. Therefore no point from $[0,T]$ (or $[0, T-1]$ if we want to be super cautious) that isn't in $A$ can be a limit point of $A$ so $A$ is closed. as we've noticed before it's countable hence has empty interior. Nevertheless - I advise you strongly to check out the modified problem with integer $m,n$ and try to justify my previous solution - it's a really nice exercise

Comment: Wait a sec, wouldn't that be the case if we were considering integer numbers in general? How can negative numbers be in the closure if all terms here are possitive? Remember $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is that reasoning still correct? If so I'm probably missing something big here!

Comment: right, my bad, I've edited the answer, but still - check out the problem I originally had in mind, you won't regret, I promise!

Comment: Oh I see, bounding the set solves it. And thanks for the modified version, it certainly does seem more interesting ;)